# How to send a post request inside of a shopware 5 controller?

Tags: shopware

Which is the correct way to send a post request inside of a Shopware controller to another shopware controller(not external site) by using default shopware methods.

I know that curl or file get contents can be used, but are there any default methods?

Comment: I think it would make sense to split the questions up, because Shopware 5 and Shopware 6 are totally different

Comment: @MichaelT let's keep this one for Shopware 5. Do you know the right way?

Comment: @David I know it already two years have passed, but may you somehow found how to?

Comment: @magnagag the curl and file_get_contents both allow you to send a post request.